# Acer a515-43 laptop boot from usb not working

Tags: windows-10, laptop, acer-aspire, usb-boot

I need to boot from usb to save my laptop files but I can’t find the option in my UEFI boot settings. And I can’t change my boot mode. The only option is UEFI.

And Under boot priority order only windows boot manager shows up. Please help.

Comment: There should be an option to disable Secure Boot. That is what prevents starting from USB.

Comment: I disabled it but the USB option is still not appearing.

Comment: If you disabled secure boot, shut down, insert the USB, and try boot .